# Drawing an area or portion of a sprite by using Group class in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sprite

I'm trying to draw an area or portion of a sprite using the Group class from the sprite module.

So I have this class to handle my sprite:
(...and yes, pygame is already imported.)

```
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, player):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load(player)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (300, 75))

        startPoint = (100, 500)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottomleft = (startPoint)
```

Then, I upload the sprite using:

```
someFile = Sprite(join('res', 'file.png'))
spriteGroup = pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates(someFile)
```

Finally, I draw it by using `spriteGroup.draw(source)`

My problem, however, is that I want to draw only a small area or portion of the original file image. Now, I know that using `Surface.blit()` I can pass an optional area rectangle representing a smaller portion of the source Surface to draw.

The Group sub-class **RenderUpdates** has a `draw()` method, so it does not accept this kind of parameters... also, `Surface.blit()` (even if I could use it) is not an option since `blit()` expects coordinates to draw the source, but I already defined these in my class from above.

So... How could I pass arguments such as `(0, 0, 75, 75)` to represent the firsts x and y, width and height, respectively, of my sprite to draw only that portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would suggest.

1. Inside of your **__init__** function, store the image in 2 variables.

   ```
   # Stores the original image
   self.ogimage = pygame.image.load(player)
   self.ogimage = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (300, 75))
   # Stores the image that is displayed to the screen
   self.image = self.ogimage
   ```
2. Then, inside of an **update** function: set a clip on the original image, get that new image, and store it in image (the one that is automatically drawn to the screen).

   ```
   def update(self):
       self.ogimage.set_clip(pygame.Rect(0, 0, 100, 100))
       self.image = self.ogimage.get_clip()
   ```

Your sprite's image is now size 100x100, as measured from the origin of the original image. You can fiddle with the **pygame.Rect** inside of **set_clip** to get the image you want.

Comment: You're a genius! I read about set_clip() but I wasn't sure how to use it on my sprite... the original image. THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to solve it. Actually, the `set_clip()` method does not work. Here is my way using `image.subsurface` [doc](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface).

```
subsurface()  
    create a new surface that references its parent
    subsurface(Rect) -> Surface
```

In your code, you can try the following to just draw `Rect(0,0,75,75)`.

```
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, player):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.original = pygame.image.load(player)
        self.original = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (300, 75))
        self.image = self.original.subsurface(Rect(0, 0, 75, 75))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Then, update`self.image` and `self.rect` inside of your `update` function.